# c# selenium if else check

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using C# with the Selenium Webdriver. I want to break the loop if the 'if' condition isn't met. My code is below. If the 'if' condition is met I want to continue the loop until it isn't.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Numara.Items.Count; i++)
        {

                driveri.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + Numara.Items[i].ToString() + "&text=");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                Actions act = new Actions(driveri);
                Thread.Sleep(500); 
            IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> rows = driveri.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/span[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div"));

            if (rows == null)
            {

               ...continuation
            }
            else
            {
               ...if there is an error

                rows.ElementAt(0).Click();
            } 
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are asking for

```
if (rows == null)
{
     continue;
}
else
{
     rows.ElementAt(0).Click();
     break;
}
```

However it'd be better code practice and more efficient to use a while loop implementation instead;

```
    IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> rows = null;

    bool rowsFound = false;
    while (!rowsFound)
    {
         rows = driveri.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/span[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div"));

         if(rows!=null)
         {
             rowsFound = true;
         }
    } 

 rows.ElementAt(0).Click();
```

On an unrelated topic, it's also bad practice to be using Thread.Sleep(), unless absolutely necessary. Most, if not all the time you will want to use WebDriverWait implementation. You can find out more about that here: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm

Answer (score 0):

The OP's issue description is quite confusing

> 1. I want to use selenium in c # to close the loop if it fails.
> 2. If the error comes out, I want to click on the link and continue the
>    loop.

If you want to **end** the loop immediately after encountering an error, use `break`.
Using `continue` on the other hand will skip the remaining statements and will go to the next iteration of your loop.

```
else
{
   ...if there is an error

    rows.ElementAt(0).Click();
    break;
}
```

Away from the topic though , I just noticed your Absolute XPATH usage. Using absolute is not really advisable, be better to use relative-concise and short xpath. An update to webapp, will surely break your xpath's of your script.